# SQL Query - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: sql

I've got two tables, one for openings and the other for bookings. An entry in the bookings table always refers to an opening and there may be multiple bookings for each opening. I would like to extract all the openings that have bookings different from `bookingType 'C'`.

> E.g.
>
> 1. if an opening has 3 bookings of type A, B and C, it should NOT show up
>      in the result
> 2. if an opening has only bookings of type A and B, it should show up in the
>      result

The following is what I've tried but it is not correct as it fails for the example 1:

```
select op.id, bo.id 
  from opening op
  left join booking bo on bo.openingId = op.id
  where bo.bookingType != 'C';
```

Here is the complete query referring to time intervals:

```
select op.id, bo.id 
  from opening op
  left join booking bo on bo.openingId = op.id
  where ((bo.arrivalDate < '2009/06/20' AND bo.departureDate <= '2009/06/20') OR 
         (bo.arrivalDate >= '2009/06/27' AND bo.departureDate > '2009/06/27'))
```

What I used to call `bookingType` was actually a time interval defined through the two columns `arrivalDate` and `departureDate`: in the example above I need all the openings that DO NOT have a booking between the `20th June 2009` and the `27th June 2009`.

Comment: Do you have your table structure? This also sounds like homework.

Comment: TABLE opening
  id INT NOT NULL
  description VARCHAR (60)
  PRIMARY KEY( id )

TABLE booking
  id INT NOT NULL,  
  openingId INT NOT NULL,
  arrivalDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  departureDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY( id )

I'm trying to extract all the openings that are available for a certain date interval (e.g. from the 20-06-2009 to the 27-06-2009)

Comment: where is the bookingType in the above example?

Comment: Use between instead of larger and smaller than.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT op.id 
FROM opening op 
WHERE op.id NOT IN 
     (SELECT b.openingid 
      FROM booking b 
      WHERE b.bookingtype='C')
```

with the date change:

```
SELECT op.id 
FROM opening op 
WHERE op.id NOT IN 
     (SELECT b.openingid 
      FROM booking b 
      WHERE (b.arrivalDate BETWEEN '2009/06/20' AND '2009/06/27') 
             OR 
            (b.departureDate BETWEEN  '2009/06/20' and '2009/06/27')
     )
```

Comment: In theory this was what I was trying to avoid... a subquery sounds a bit heavy, but it works

Comment: Consider the left join syntax solution from aaron as well. A left join is often faster than a not in subquery.

Comment: A good SQL database will usually optimize a subquery into a left join so it has the same performance.  Write the statement with a subquery - it's eaasier to code and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy version without joins, you don't even need the Openings table:

```
select openingId, id
from booking
where openingId not in (
    select openingId
    from booking
    where bookingType = 'C'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Frankie - No need for a NOT IN clause.  You can use a Left-Anti-Semi Join as well - like this:

```
SELECT op.id 
FROM opening op 
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b ON op.id = b.openingid AND b.bookingtype = 'C'
WHERE b.OpeningID IS NULL
```

and this:

```
SELECT op.id 
FROM opening op 
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b ON op.id = b.OpeningID
 AND b.ArrivalDate BETWEEN '2009/06/20' AND '2009/06/27'  
 AND b.DepartureDate BETWEEN '2009/06/20' AND '2009/06/27'
WHERE b.OpeningID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select opid, boid from 
   (select op.id opid, bo.id boid, bo.bookingType bookingType 
       from 
       openings op left outer join bookings bo on op.id = bo.id
   )
where bookingType <> 'C'
```

Comment: Actually... it does a left outer join. And the main query filters the result of the left outer join...

Comment: But a left outer join and where can be done without a subquery?